# How is the formula for the base current value derived in a three-phase per-unit system?

Tags: power, current

When analysing a power system using the [per-unit system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-unit_system) for a three phase system, why is \$S_b = \sqrt{3}*V_b*I_b\$, where as shown in the link, \$S_b\$ is the base power value, \$V_b\$ is the base voltage value and \$I_b\$ is the base current value?

Comment: What is §b, Vb and Ib?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was getting used to MathJax.

Comment: Are you ok with the sqrt 3 or is it the problem?

Comment: The sqrt(3) is the problem.

Comment: Do you understand why sqrt3 is used in regular 3 phase for converting phase voltage to line voltage? In other words is this a general 3-phase question about sqrt3. I'm asking this because I'm not familiar with the per-unit system but I know standard 3-phase stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three phase circuits in power systems can be connected in two ways, delta connection or a wye connection. Luckily, both of these circuits have the same equation for apparent power.

\$S=\sqrt{3}VI\text{*}\$

It is this insight that allows for the current formula, despite the relation between line/phase voltage/current being different for the delta and the wye circuit.

Comment: It's better to emphasise the voltage is phase-to-phase.